# Monitor Standby Script on 23.04 - ASROCK N100

Tags: display, standby

I'm using a N100 as home server.
The server has two Displays attached to function as general purpouse information display.
My goal is to turn it off if noone is present.
I'm currently looking into methods to send both displays to standby, however i did not succeed.

My approach was to find and test commands over remote ssh.

First i looked into cec, however it seems not to be working with Ubuntu. (same issue below)
[Why ubuntu doesn't support HDMI CEC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1295937/why-ubuntu-doesnt-support-hdmi-cec)

Then I looked into xset, however that does not work as well.

```
export DISPLAY=":0" // or export DISPLAY="0"
sudo xset dpms off
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified
xset:  unable to open display ":0"
```

I could not figure out how to fix permissions :/

I also tried xrandr with similar issues

```
sudo xrandr -display :0 --output DP1 --off
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

Can't open display :0
```

I also tested the commands locally on the machine without success.

I'm using the default configuratation for X (no custom xorg.conf) so i guess display 0 should work.

I'm guessing this could be a permission issue but I have no clue on how to give permission to the respective tools.

Anny help / hints on how to fix this much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Wayland in `/etc/gdm/custom.conf`

Now DPMS can be used to manage monitor power state like

```
xset -display :0  dpms force off

xset -display :0  dpms force on
```